# Hiding Cells in Excel with a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am desperatly looking for help with my excel macro to hide rows if a certain criteria is met. I have tried to enter all the code previously provided in other question answers and just cannot get the damn thing to run.

My code below runs wonderfully without the row hidden part

I need the following to calc before the template is generated

```
If range F30 to J30 is blank then rows 29 to 30 must be hidden
If range F33 to J33 is blank then rows 32 to 33 must be hidden
If range F30 to J33 is blank then rows 28 to 35 must be hidden
```

Can you please assist me

```cs
Function RangeName(sName As String) As String
RangeName = Application.Substitute(sName, " ", "_")
End Function
Sub MergePrint()
Dim wsForm As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet
Dim sRngName As String, r As Long, c As Integer
Set wsForm = Worksheets("Template")
Set wsData = Worksheets("DataSource")
With wsData.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
For r = 2 To .Rows.Count
If Not wsData.Cells(r, 1).EntireRow.Hidden Then
For c = 1 To .Columns.Count
sRngName = wsData.Cells(1, c).Value
Range(RangeName(sRngName)).Value = wsData.Cells(r, c)
Next
wsForm.PrintOut
End If
Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Does it return an error, or does it not hide the rows? Worth stepping through the code using F8 and ensuring that the loops are running through every cell that you want them to - may be worth trying `wsData.UsedRange` rather than CurrentRegion for instance.

Comment: Matt - I'm not sure how to add the criteria for hiding the rows in the code below. At the moment it only merges the data to the template sheet so the code above works 100%. It is when i try to add the hide rows command all hell breaks loose. Could you insert the code for me? Or do you have an email address i can send the template to so you can work from there?

Comment: @AnnelizeStoltz try my solution below.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way.  I'm sure there's a way to not use so many if statements...

```
Sub Test()
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    With Sheet1
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("F30:J30")) = 0 Then
            .Range("F29:J30").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            .Range("F29:J30").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("F33:J33")) = 0 Then
            .Range("F32:J33").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            .Range("F32:J33").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("F30:J33")) = 0 Then
            .Range("F28:J35").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            .Range("F28:J35").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: you could use a `SELECT CASE` ... but the issue here is that the rules overlap one another, plus as you can see in the comments below my answer, the OP doesn't want to learn or try anything - just be given the code

Comment: Yeah, I thought about SELECT CASE, but couldn't think of a good implementation because of the overlap.  As far as wanting to be given an answer, I'm hoping that my code will be a closer to a a "plug and chug" implementation while still being simple enough that they can learn from...wishful thinking, I know, but I thought I'd give it a shot...

Comment: @philip and sous2817, thank you very much for the assistance. I am struggling to get it to run but will persist until it does. You guys are rock stars

Comment: @AnnelizeStoltz no problem. We'll get it sorted out.  When you say you're struggling to get it to run, what do you mean? Like you don't know how to execute the code, it's not giving your the expected results, you're getting an error message.  Can you be a bit more descriptive?

Comment: It only runs for one record but ignores the extra info in the datasource.

Comment: so my guess is that what you'd like hidden isn't what you said in your original post.  The code should work for the criteria you laid out originally.  If your request is more generic, can you edit your question and describe exactly what you're looking for rather than us trying to assume what you're after?

Comment: Good morning Sous2817. I couldnt get your code above to run. Im not really a VB coder and specialize in payroll/HR software and reporting. I usually only work with ODBC queries. After much research on the net I found the code below and it runs for just the last record. Is there an email address I can send the doc to for you to have a look at?

Comment: I'm not sure how to send a private message and I'd rather not post my email address on a public forum.  Can you post your doc on a file sharing site and share the link?

Answer (score 1):

you could use formulas to mark a row for hiding, then use **SpecialCells** to return the rows that need to be hidden and set the `hidden` property to true or false.

in another column (for example, column N) add this formula:

`=IF(LEN(CONCATENATE(F:F,G:G,H:H,I:I,J:J))=0,NA(),"")`

you can also put this formula in programmatically using VBA:
`Range("N28:N35").Formula = "=IF(LEN(CONCATENATE(F:F,G:G,H:H,I:I,J:J))=0,NA(),"""")"`

this will check the cells, and return an `#N/A` error if they are all blank.

Now you can use the SpecialCells function in VBA to select the rows to be hidden:

`Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).EntireRow.Hidden = True`

Comment: Philip, I already have an IF statement in the rows that must be hidden.(=IF(F30+J30>0,"   - Executive Share Awards","")) My problem however is to add this command to my code above without getting "end if without if" or "end with without with" errors. Can you let me know where to insert this in the code above?

Comment: Do you have an email address i can send the template to?

Comment: Im not really a VB coder and have been trying to get assistance for the last 2 days. It will take someone like you probably 2 minutes to add the code.I feel like jumping out the window already!

Comment: On SO we prefer to *teach someone how to fish, rather than just giving them a fish*

Comment: Here are some websites that will help you to **learn VBA**: [Ozgrid MVP Free Excel VBA Training](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/free-training/basic-index.htm) and [VBTutor.com: Excel VBA Course](http://excelvbatutor.com/index.php/tutorial/) AND [MSDN Library: Getting Started with VBA in Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737.aspx)

Comment: :( , Im on a deadline but thanks for assisting. Have a good day.